# Timestamp is different in flutter from Firestore and Postman

Tags: python, flutter, dart

In my app, when the user adds a document, I store the timestamp of the document creation.

My app calls an api written in Flask.
I store the timestamp in python with:

```
timestamp = firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
```

The timestamp is stored in Firestore as: [image]

When the user requests the document, I process the timestamp to be shown in a readable way with the following code:

```
def get_proper_timestamp(timestamp) -> str:
    if not timestamp:
        return None

    date: datetime.date = timestamp.date()

    day = str(date.day)
    month = str(date.month)
    year = str(date.year)

    if len(month) == 1:
        month = f"0{month}"

    proper_date = f"{day} {month} {year}"

    weekday: int = date.weekday()
    proper_weekday: str = get_day_from_int(weekday)

    time = timestamp.time()
    hour = time.hour
    minute = time.minute
    temp = strptime(f"{hour}:{minute}", "%H:%M")

    proper_time: str = strftime("%I:%M %p", temp)

    return f"{proper_weekday}, {proper_date}.{proper_time}"


def get_day_from_int(integer: int) -> str:
    mapper = {
        0: "Mon",
        1: "Tues",
        2: "Wed",
        3: "Thur",
        4: "Fri",
        5: "Sat",
        6: "Sun",
    }
    return mapper[integer]
```

In Postman, this outputs:
[image]

My flutter code reads the timestamp in a straight-forward way:

```
List<DataCell> _buildCells(Map<String, dynamic> entry) {
    String timestamp = entry["timestamp"];
    print(timestamp);
    
    return [
      DataCell(Text(entry["timestamp"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(entry["amount"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(entry["after"].toString()))
    ];
  }
```

This outputs: [image]

This is four hours before. Which I think it means that I'm the UTF offset somewhere.
But why is Postman showing the date correctly?

I'd actually prefer flask to return the raw timestamp, but I couldn't deserialize it.
I read most the answers on SO on this issue, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Dart problem since all your Dart code does is to print the `String` it received.  If that string isn't correct, then the problem is with whatever code generated the string.  Also, it's usually easier to send timestamps as integers representing [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in Firestore is an internal structure, which is timezone agnostic (internally based on UTC).

The value you see in the Firestore console has been localized to your local timezone for your convenience, which is apparently UTC+4.

The value you get when fetching the time with Flutter is a Timestamp, also UTC-based and timezone agnostic.  When you convert that with .toDate() (or the equivalent with millisecondsSinceEpoch), it becomes a traditional DateTime, which is internally in UTC, but carries a localtime offset, and normally displays itself as localtime.  This is probably the value you are seeing as +4.